# How to grab a node index inside an Hbox

Tags: javafx

I tried to add Buttons in to an Hbox i wanna grab the index when a button clicked
here is what i have done.

```
    HBox gp = new HBox(10);
    gp.setPadding(new Insets(3));

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        JFXButton jb = new JFXButton("Number " + i);
        jb.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgb(230, 126, 34)");

        jb.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                System.out.println("index no?");
            }
        });
        jb.setMinWidth(100);
        jb.setMinHeight(50);
        gp.getChildren().add(jb);
    }

    gp.prefWidthProperty().bind(topscroll.widthProperty());
    topscroll.setContent(gp);


    gp.prefWidthProperty().bind(topscroll.widthProperty());
    topscroll.setContent(gp);
```

any suggestion to achieve that?

Comment: if you call event.getSource() inside your handle method you will be able to get the button which triggers the event isn't that enough?

Comment: @JKostikiadis If all that's needed is to get the button, you don't even need to call `event.getSource()`: the button that triggers the event is `jb`, which you can access in the event handler (it is "effectively final").

Comment: @James_D Of course, but still to be honest I prefer to actual call the event.getSource() for readability purposes. Especially when the method is more than 10-15 lines ( for some reason :P )

Comment: is there any way to add a mouse event to the Hbox and get the button index? coz with the for loop the efficiency is reduced.

Comment: i used a vbox instead a button. and add few other nodes. now i wanna find a way to change value in that vbox children anybody know? i tried
vbox.getChildren().get(1) but inside this vbox there is an hbox also. i wanna change the values inside that hbox how do i do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can just copy the index into a final variable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    JFXButton jb = new JFXButton("Number " + i);
    jb.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgb(230, 126, 34)");

    int index = i ;

    jb.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            System.out.println("index no: " + index);
        }
    });
    jb.setMinWidth(100);
    jb.setMinHeight(50);
    gp.getChildren().add(jb);
}
```

Note you can get the button directly (in case that is all you need) without creating another variable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    JFXButton jb = new JFXButton("Number " + i);
    jb.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgb(230, 126, 34)");

    jb.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            System.out.println("Click on "+jb.getText());
        }
    });
    jb.setMinWidth(100);
    jb.setMinHeight(50);
    gp.getChildren().add(jb);
}
```

Comment: Thanx mate for making new year worthwhile! ha ha cheers! Happy new year!!